# How do you add google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm following [the instructions](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1042508) but where the heck is "+ New Web Property"?

This is how mine looks after clicking the admin tab and choosing the account:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have insuficent privellages.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to admin in the top toolbar and select the tracking code tab. I will a attach a picture for you. There are more instructions on the page.
[image]

EDIT:
To get to this window you first have to click on of the properties and pull up that dashboard. Each profile has a different Tracking ID. After you have the Individual property pulled up you can then click on admin, and select the Tracking Code tab.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect what to do from the screen you have added to your question.